# Chrome is not displaying XSLT

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome, xslt

I got a problem regarding XSLT rendering.

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/xslt/week.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE week SYSTEM "https://planner.schimweg.net/dtd/teamplanner.dtd">
<week xmlns="https://planner.schimweg.net/dtd/teamplanner.dtd">
  <day date="2019-07-01">
    <job id="4" timeFrom="11:00" timeTo="12:00" duration="60" name="End">
      <description>Ende</description>
      <member id="1"/>
      <member id="4"/>
    </job>
    <job id="5" timeFrom="12:00" timeTo="18:00" duration="600" name="QA">
      <member id="1"/>
    </job>
  </day>
  <team name="SuperTeam">
    <description>My Team! Yeah!</description>
    <memberDefinition id="1" name="Luca" leader="true" you="true"/>
    <memberDefinition id="4" name="Hendrik"/>
  </team>
</week>
```

And the XSLT belonging to it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:n="https://planner.schimweg.net/dtd/teamplanner.dtd" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="n:week">
    <html>
        <body>

        <h1><xsl:value-of select="//n:team/@name"/></h1>
        <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="//n:day">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
                <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select=".//n:job">
                    <li><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></li>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is, while the page is rendering in Firefox and Edge just fine, in Chrome and Safari a blank page is displayed, with the only element being added to the DOM in Chrome being
[image: a single Element in DOM]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Do I have to manually activate XSLT in Chrome?

Best regards,
Luca

Comment: Do you load the XML document over HTTP(S) or from the file system?

Comment: Also Mozilla ignores external DTDs but I am not sure Chrome or Webkit do. When I check your linked DTD in oXygen it shows an error "Open quote is expected for attribute "name" associated with an  element type  "memberDefinition"  for line 16 of the DTD. So first try to fix the DTD or try the XSLT without the DTD being referenced in the XML. Perhaps that helps with Chrome.

Comment: @MartinHonnen yeah, thanks, I fixed my DTD and it works now, I was expecting my IDE to hightlight errors in it, but it didn't...
It seems like Firefox is ignoring the DTD, Chrome is checking it.